# Jest-puppeteer Testing Request Interception Unexpected End of Input

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, jestjs, puppeteer

So I am new to writing test and I am having an issue I do not quite understand. I keep getting this syntax error:

```
       SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

   95 | })
   96 | describe('Renders Home Page', () => {
>  97 |   test('Intercept Request', async () => {
      |   ^
   98 |     await page.waitForSelector('body > #root > .default-blank-container > .default-login > button')
   99 |     const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({
  100 |       waitUntil: ['networkidle2']
```

Here is the current code I am running. The code runs, logs in then shuts down with this syntax error that VS Code is not catching. I have found I ran into this issue several times. Please help me bridge this gap of understanding.

```js
// // /*
// // Testing Using jest puppeteer. Test ENV Preconfigured so no need to import puppeteer. See More With Documentation at
// //   Testing Documentation- https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer
// // */
const timeout = 26000;
var hasLoggedIn = false;
var user = 'someuser'
var pw = 'somepassword'


beforeAll(async () => {
  jest.setTimeout(200000)
  await page.goto('http://localhost:5000/login', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  });
  page.setViewport({
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  })
  page.setRequestInterception(true)
  page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    if (interceptedRequest.url().endsWith('v1/user')) {
      hasLoggedIn ?
        interceptedRequest.respond({
          content: 'application/json',
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            success: true,
            user: {
              created_at: "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              email: "myemail.com",
              firstname: "Dev",
              lastname: "Eddoen",
              permission: [],
              session: "_e0d7db00-7a93-0137-e0dd-03bfe620dd3b",
              updated_at: "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              _v: 0,
              _id: "123456789"
            }
          })
        }) :
        request.respond({
          content: 'application/json',
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            success: false
          })
        })
    } else if (interceptedRequest.url().endsWith(`/v1/login`)) {
      var url = request.url()
      url = url.split("=")
      interceptedRequest.respond({
          status: 302,
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Location": "http://localhost:5000",
            "set-cookie": `userKey=${url[1]}`
          }
        }),
        hasLoggedIn = true
    } else {
      interceptedRequest.continue();
    }
  })
})
describe('Renders Home Page', () => {
  test('Intercept Request', async () => {
    await page.waitForSelector('body > #root > .default-blank-container > .default-login > button')
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({
      waitUntil: ['networkidle2']
    })
    page.authenticate({
      username: user,
      password: pw
    })
    await page.click('body > #root > .default-blank-container > .default-login > button')
    await navigationPromise
    await page.waitForSelector('button.mui-btn.mui-btn--small.mui-btn--raised')
    const logout = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('button.mui-btn.mui-btn--small.mui-btn--raised'));
    expect(logout).toContain('Settings')
  });
})
```